# How to write dataframe data into json file as json non array objects?

Tags: python, json, jsonlines

I have data in Pandas dataframe and I am able to write the dataframe data into JSON file by calling:

```
df.to_json('filepath', orient='records')
```

This writes data into json file as an **array** of JSON objects.

> [{"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}]

I want data in the json file to be as below i.e. just comma seperated JSON objects **without array**

> {"col 1":"a","col 2":"b"},{"col 1":"c","col 2":"d"}

Would appreciate any help. I am new to python and not able to find the way. Thank you.

Comment: what you want is not valid JSON ... and Pandas knows that

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest http://jsonlines.org/ technically, it isn't _invalid_...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, try ANY JSON processor or JSON validator - and you'll understand. What he wants is text, not valid JSON

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest True that it isn't valid *JSON*, but it's a valid _JSON file format_, that's all I meant to say, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Also, I assumed this is how OP wants it written to the file, seeing as they are calling `to_json` with a filepath.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for mentioning that, the output file is processed by another program and it is failing with an array of JSON objects. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so you want a [JSON *line*](http://jsonlines.org) file. You could do that in a similar fashion. Call `to_dict` and write to a file in a loop.

```
with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    for x in df.to_dict(orient='r'):
        f.write(json.dumps(x) + '\n')
```

---

Alternatively, call `to_json` in a loop:

```
with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    for _, r in df.iterrows():
        r.to_json(f); f.write('\n')
```

Comment: I thank you for your help. It worked exactly as I wanted.